# Create Barplot with Top 5 Only

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Simple question that is troubling me.  How can I create a barplot with only the Top 5 bars for a data frame based on a single column?

```
barplot(table(DF$COLUMN))
```

I just want the top 5 bars only because the column has many different values and the chart is clustered with bars rendering the graph useless.  The top 5 only would make the picture clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
  count(carb) %>%
  slice_max(n, n = 5, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carb, n)) + geom_col()
```

[image]